# Add category description on product page (Woocommerce)

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, categories

I'm using Woocommerce as a catalog for a website.

I would like to show the category description in every product page.

It's that possibile by editing my theme or maybe with a plugin? I can't find anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you want to show the category description in every product page means on product detail page??? and also share a screenshot of that so I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This will display the categories.

```
<?php
    $args = array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat');
    $terms = get_terms('product_cat', $args);
    $count = count($terms); 

    if ($count > 0) {
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            echo '<p>' . $term->description . '</p>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Where you put it depends on your theme.  In your theme or child theme you need to create these folders `woocommerce > single-product > meta.php`.

You will most likely need to edit the above code for your needs but it should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add this to your functions.php file of your child theme.

```
function display_product_category_descriptions(){
  global $product;

  $terms = get_the_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat');

  foreach ($terms as $term) {
    echo '<p>' . $term->description  . '</p>';
  }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'display_product_category_descriptions', 45);
```